# WordPress - Use user meta for if else statement in 'user_register' hook

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to access user meta by $wpdb query after a user registers.
What I am trying to do is to make 2 different custom post types if a user is a freelancer or an employer.

here is the code:

```
add_action('user_register','registration_funtion', 999);
function registration_funtion($uid){
global $wpdb;
        $existsD = $wpdb->get_var( $wpdb->prepare(
                "SELECT meta_value FROM wp_usermeta WHERE user_id = '%s' AND meta_key = 'user_reg_type'" , $uid
            ));
 if($existsD == "userfreelancer"){
                
                $my_post_2 = array(
                    'post_title' => sanitize_text_field($user_info->user_login),
                    'post_status' => 'publish',
                    'post_author' => $uid,
                    'post_type' => 'freelancer',
                    'post_content' => $existsD.'-'.$uid 
                    
                );
$freelancer_id = wp_insert_post($my_post_2);
} elseif($existsD == "useremployer") { 
                
                $my_post = array(
                    'post_title' => sanitize_text_field($user_info->user_login),
                    'post_status' => 'publish',
                    'post_author' => $uid,
                    'post_type' => 'employer',
                    'post_content' => $existsD.'-'.$uid                  
                );
        
                $company_id = wp_insert_post($my_post);
}
```

Problem is its just takes the first if statement and completely ignores the else if statement.

Thanks in advance.
Regards,

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
add_action('user_register','registration_funtion', 999);
function registration_funtion($uid){

        global $wpdb;
        $existsD = get_user_meta($uid, 'user_reg_type');

        if($existsD == "userfreelancer"){
                
                $my_post_2 = array(
                    'post_title' => sanitize_text_field($user_info->user_login),
                    'post_status' => 'publish',
                    'post_author' => $uid,
                    'post_type' => 'freelancer',
                    'post_content' => $existsD.'-'.$uid 
                    
                );
                $freelancer_id = wp_insert_post($my_post_2);
        }elseif($existsD == "useremployer") { 
                
                $my_post = array(
                    'post_title' => sanitize_text_field($user_info->user_login),
                    'post_status' => 'publish',
                    'post_author' => $uid,
                    'post_type' => 'employer',
                    'post_content' => $existsD.'-'.$uid                  
                );
        
                $company_id = wp_insert_post($my_post);
        }
```

Comment: Check you meta value is same as you mentioned in if else conditions.

Comment: Now it's not making any of the two custom post types

Comment: What is the output of this `get_user_meta($uid, 'user_reg_type')`?

Comment: It seems its empty

Comment: And data you get previously? By using `$existsD = $wpdb->get_var( $wpdb->prepare(
                "SELECT meta_value FROM wp_usermeta WHERE user_id = '%s' AND meta_key = 'user_reg_type'" , $uid
            ));`

Comment: That creates both post types freelancer and employer

Comment: What is the output of this code `$existsD = $wpdb->get_var( $wpdb->prepare(                 "SELECT meta_value FROM wp_usermeta WHERE user_id = '%s' AND meta_key = 'user_reg_type'" , $uid             ));`

Comment: Check mapping in db for user id and user type.

Comment: DB value is correct its what user selects from radio button freelancer or employer

Comment: What is the output of this code $existsD = $wpdb->get_var( $wpdb->prepare(                 "SELECT meta_value FROM wp_usermeta WHERE user_id = '%s' AND meta_key = 'user_reg_type'" , $uid             ));

Comment: userfreelancer or useremployer

Comment: Depending upon what radio value user chooses

Comment: So if `$existsD` is `userfreelancer` then it creates the post `freelancer`. And if `$existsD` is `useremployer` then it creates the post `employer`. Right?

Comment: Yes exactly. you got it

Comment: Then it's working fine. What is the problem?

Comment: Not exactly its not creating any of the two post types

Comment: So problem is post is not creating.

Comment: Yes its like its not reading the meta also get_user_meta($uid, 'user_reg_type')[0] shows userfreelancer1 adding 1 at the end

Comment: use this `get_user_meta($uid, 'user_reg_type', true)` then check output.

Comment: its printing u1

Comment: use only `get_user_meta($uid, 'user_reg_type', true)`. remove `[0]` & 1 etc.

Comment: Yeah now its good printing userfreelancer

Comment: Now it should create post for `freelancer`. check it

Comment: I will do a test and reply. will you be here?

Comment: Yes. Also check with other user having meta key `user_reg_type`.

Comment: Is there any user have `useremployer`?

Comment: For the moment just one

Comment: Is your post created for `freelancer`?

Comment: No its so strange

Comment: Problem is this this block of code `$my_post_2 = array(
                    'post_title' => sanitize_text_field($user_info->user_login),
                    'post_status' => 'publish',
                    'post_author' => $uid,
                    'post_type' => 'freelancer',
                    'post_content' => $existsD.'-'.$uid 
                    
                );
$freelancer_id = wp_insert_post($my_post_2);`

Comment: Check it it creating any post or not?

Comment: Check this https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_insert_post/

Comment: Testing will get back to you

Comment: Can i select post type like this 'post_type' => $existsD,

Comment: How do I select which post type to add

Comment: What kind of post types you have?

Comment: trying something like this:

Comment: $my_post = array(
           'post_title' => sanitize_text_field($user_info->user_login),
           'post_status' => 'publish',
           'post_author' => $uid,
           'post_type' => $existsD,
                    'post_content' => $existsD.'-'.$uid 
                    
          );
          $freelancer_id = wp_insert_post($my_post);

Comment: What kind of post types you have in your system.

Comment: post_type=freelancer and post_type=employer

Comment: Use it and check for post type freelancer in you wp admin

Comment: Didnt create, thats what i am saying its not able to read meta value after registration

Comment: Yes confirmed, it created a normal blog post with content -117 (117 is the id)

Comment: Try this  `$my_post_2 = array(
                    'post_title' => 'Test title',
                    'post_status' => 'publish',
                    'post_author' => $uid,
                    'post_type' => 'post',
                    'post_content' => 'Post-'.$uid 
                    
                );`

Comment: check this `$user_info->user_login`.

Comment: I think you do not have blog post type `freelancer` & `employer`. So it may not displaying.

Comment: I have both post type set

Comment: User_reg_type the meta to check freelancer or employer

Comment: 56 min ago you said you were getting the data. For `user_reg_type`.

Comment: Yes but in user_register its not reading meta